# How do LSTMs utilize input data in practice?

Tags: keras, neural-network, lstm

I am learning neural networking and I am trying to implement and understand LSTM and other recurrent NNs with Keras.

I have been trying to understand them by reading articles and books, in particular: [this](https://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/). But I am having trouble connecting the theory to real examples.

For example I have time-series data which I have reformatted into a three dimensional array. My array has size (12000,60,1) and the goal is to predict the next step. My understanding is that my time-step is then 60.

> How is this data, in particular the time-step, utilized by the LSTM structure?

My current idea is that, in reference to the diagram, the LSTM takes the first 60-step array and uses the first element as X_0, it then 'does what LSTM cells do' and the updated cell state is passed onto the next cell where X_1 is inputted and the process is repeated.

[image]

Now when each of the 60 elements has passed through each of their cells we then have 60 nodes (h0 to h59) which then feed into an output node to predict the next step. The final cell state is then the first cell state of the next array and the next array of 60 is run through in the same manner.

> Is this the correct? I am doubtful of my understanding, in particular as to whether the final cell state gets carried to the next array.

If all of this is correct, what does the 50 in LSTM(50) indicate relative to my understanding?

Comment: I think your first guess is correct. And your second one is correct too, if you set "stateful=true". If "stateful=false" the cell state and hidden state are getting resetted after every 60 timesteps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your explanation is correct, the state is kept and updated across timesteps.

The first parameter of the `LSTM` layer is the number of neurons, or better said, the dimensionality of the output and the hidden state. Remember the hidden state is a vector, and the dimensions of the internal weight matrices that transform from input to hidden state, hidden to hidden state (recurrent), and hidden state to output are determined by this parameter.

So as in a `Dense` layer, a `LSTM(50)` will have a 50-dimensional output vector, and additionally the hidden state of the recurrent layer will also be 50-dimensional.